# Full code - Strongly typed Models.Error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, models

Model : (file name : Class1.cs)

```
namespace Project
{
    public class Class1

   {
      // attributes defined : title, date etc
   }


    public class Class1DBContext : DbContext

   {

     public DbSet<Class1> Class1Table{ get; set; }

   }

    public class Class2

   {
       // attributes defined : Name, Location etc

   }

    public class Class2DBContext : DbContext

   {
         public DbSet<Class2> Class2Table{ get; set; }
   }

   public class ParentView

   {
        public Class1 Class1{ get; set; }
        public Class2 Class2{ get; set; }
   }

}
```

In Class1Controller.cs file:

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{ 
   public class Class1Controller : Controller
   {
       private Class1DBContext db = new Class1DBContext();


    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Class1Table.ToList());
    }
 }
```

In Index.cshtml :

```
Index view:

@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ParentView>


@{
   ViewBag.Title = "List";
 }

 <div style="float:left;">
 <h1 style="color:Black;" >List</h1>
 </div>
 <div>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
       <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1.Title)
       </td>

       <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1.Description)
       </td>
     </tr>
   }

</div>
<div>
   @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartialNew");}

</div>
```

in partial view code (partialNew.cshtml):

```
  @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ParentView>

  @foreach (var item in Model) 
   {
   <tr>
       <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class2.Name)
       </td>
       <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class2.Location)
       </td>
    </tr>
   }
```

Error Message:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Class1]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.ParentView]'.

Answer (score 2):

Change the class to use make use of IEnumerable, e.g.:

```
public class ParentView  
{ 
  public IEnumerable<Class1> Class1{ get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Class2> Class2{ get; set; } 
}
```

Remove IEnumerable so that it reads:

```
@model Project.Models.ParentView
```

Answer (score 1):

Your passing a list of Class1 objects to a view that requires a list of ParentView objects. The error message is very clear here.

What is your question exactly?

Edit -

You need to return the correct type to the view, maybe something like:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var pv = new ParentView();
    pv.Class1 = db.Class1Table.ToList();
    pv.Class2 = db.Class2Table.ToList();

    return View(pv);
}
```

Comment: well, I had classes code...class1 and class1dbcontext originally in my code. The line return View(db.Class1Table.ToList()); worked well. Then I added Classes class2, class2dbcontext, parentview.. the reason I added the additional classes in the model is because I wanted to render a partial view based on class2 in the index page. and then ofcourse I changed the code @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Class1> to @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.ParentView> in the view pages.

Comment: I am getting cannot implicitly convert List to Model squiggly error. at line 4 of your code block. Another thing is it will not give me intellisense option for Class2Table in line 5 of code .. may be because of my earlier statement (in my original post) private Class1DBContext db = new Class1DBContext(); (In Class1Controller.cs file: code above)

Comment: The ParentView class needs to be lists of Class1 & 2 types. These are terrible names btw, It's getting me all confused! :)

Comment: Couldnt agree more :-) Bad choice of words. I realized that long back, it was too late. Did not want to make it even more complicated by changing them midway.

Comment: @asawyer: I made them lists in the parentview class defintion. That is making the code break in the index page..                               <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class1.Title)
</td> because Class1 is now a list. There is a red squiggly underline for the atttribute name (title)